# Stripe API subscriptions flow?

Tags: stripe-payments

Using Node.js

I got a question with the flow of the API.

My web app allows users to use the site for free but gives them a choice to "subscribe" to other users and view their premium content which charges them monthly.

Looking at the stripe API, to add a subscription to a user, I would need `customer object`. Would the proper flow of this be:

1. User signs up and in the backend, create a stripe customer for said user and save the id into my user object database.
2. When user subscribes to another user, grab their customer id from the database and create the subscription.

Also side question, does this allow for multiple subscriptions of the same product? Because a user can subscribe to multiple users

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of Customers sounds correct; you collect a user's credit card details, create a Customer object, then using that id, sign the Customer up for a Subscription.

With a Stripe Subscription you can use `quantity` or have multiple `subscription items` attached to a single Subscription. So if the user already has an active subscription, you could grab this and increase the quantity or add a second plan.

e.g. you could bill a user for `Plan A` and `Plan B` on a single Subscription, or `2 x Plan A`, etc

see:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/create#create_subscription_item-quantity

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/create